# Visualize clock effect by coloring ggplot data bases on criteria

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the correlation between the scheduled arrival time and the actual arrival time of data in the flights package.

Doing this I generated the plot as shown here:
[image]
Code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
attach(flights)

ggplot(flights, aes(x = sched_arr_time, y = arr_time)) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, color='darkblue', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(method="auto", se=TRUE, fullrange=FALSE, level=0.95, color='red')
```

I would like to color all data that is effected by the clock passing 00.00 orange.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you made a mistake in your question because based on your conditions all points will be orange.

Anyway, if you would like to color conditionally your points, there is multiple ways of doing it, you can for example create an extra column with an `ifelse` statement containing your color of interest, then plot your points using the new column as `color` argument in your `aes` and call `scale_color_identity` function to apply the color pattern contained in this column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
flights %>% mutate(Color = ifelse(sched_arr_time < 2400 & arr_time  > 0, "orange","darkblue")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sched_arr_time, y = arr_time, color = Color))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_smooth(color = "red")+
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: My logic is indeed wrong. I need to check if the clock has gone round (passed midnight).

Comment: I think values are expressed in minutes (not sure). Anyway, this method is pretty generic and you can apply it for whenever conditions you would like to check.